# Aggregate these user login counts based on 10 minute time intervals

Tags: r, machine-learning, statistics, time-series, forecasting

I have included a snapshot of the raw data frame below, I am trying to aggregate these login counts based on 10 minute time intervals, and visualiz and describe the result of the time series of the user login counts that best shows a pattern. I dont know how to best do this? Thanks!

```
print(head(logins.data.frame))
```

the below is the snapshot of the raw data frame

```
#DateTime
#1 2012-03-01T00:05:55+00:00
#2 2012-03-01T00:06:23+00:00
#3 2012-03-01T00:06:52+00:00
#4 2012-03-01T00:11:23+00:00
#5 2012-03-01T00:12:47+00:00
#6 2012-03-01T00:12:54+00:00
```

Comment: Those look like xts records. You should post `dput( head( logins.data.frame)) ` as an [edit] to make this an [MCVE]

Answer (score 1):

Let's say your data looks like this:

```
dates = as.POSIXct(c("2012-03-01 00:05:55+00:00", "2012-03-01 00:06:23+00:00","2012-03-01 00:06:52+00:00", "2012-03-01 00:11:23+00:00", "2012-03-01 00:12:47+00:00", "2012-03-01 00:12:54+00:00"))
```

Convert the time into minutes (I assume all data is on the same day, but it wouldn't be hard to generalise that assumption):

```
minutes = as.numeric(format(dates, "%M")) + 60 * as.numeric(format(dates, "%H"))
```

And bucket the minutes in the usual R way.  Here's how I'd do it:

```
minute.max = ceiling(max(minutes))
bins = cut(minutes, breaks = 10*0:minute.max, labels = as.character(10*0:(minute.max-1)))
```

Put it all together:

```
df = data.frame(dates = dates, minutes = minutes, bins = bins)
```

Comment: Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos): (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'double'
Traceback:

Comment: that is the error I got when i tried to convert time to minutes

Comment: What is the format of your dates? Can you include the date in your question?

Comment: this is what was returned to me which looks very wrong..... I want to aggregate the data so its split up into 15 minute time intervals `              dates minutes bins
1 2010-01-01 00:11:52      11    0
2 2010-01-01 00:13:00      13    0
3 2010-01-01 00:14:49      14    0
4 2010-01-01 00:21:00      21   15
5 2010-01-01 00:23:05      23   15
6 2010-01-01 00:29:00      29   15` and i aggregated them by 15 minutes instead

Comment: If you can include the data in your question, perhaps by using `dput`, then anyone could answer your question without starting a private tutoring session.